# Port forwarding not working only for devices connected on same wifi

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

So I have a .NET server running on my desktop.  https://192.168.0.xxx:7089/WeatherForecast

192.168.0.xxx is also my ipv4 address.

Now, I am trying to access this from outside world. I barely know anything about networking but I know that 192 is private IP address and therefore it's not exposed to the internet.
So now the question is how do I access it from outside?

This is how I have configured port forwarding. The IP which is hidden is my dynamic IPv4 of my computer where the webserver is running.

[port forwarding configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PAa2.png)

I tried to access https://192.168.0.xxx:8181/WeatherForecast from outside but I couldn't.

So I tried IP of my router 100.71.xx.xx and it worked! I was able to hit the API from another device(smart phone) at home which is on the same wifi. But as soon as I turn the wifi off and switch to cellular data, it stops working.

I just did a quick what's my IP and found and IP that starts with 1.186.xxx.... and tried that. It didn't work either. :/

Comment: This is a fairly common question on the site – look up "CGNAT".

Comment: how many routers do you have? it looks like you are concerned about 3 networks, so unless you have two routers, it is likely CGNAT, which is bad. It is a little unusual that you can connect to the routers external IP address from your wifi. usually that requires a feature called NAT Hairpinning, which is not common in standard home Internet access routers. if you do have two routers, then you likely have a double-NAT scenario, and you need to port forward from the outter router to the inner router, and then from the inner router to the device.

Comment: “But as soon as I turn the wifi off and switch to cellular data, it stops working.” - Why did you disconnect from your WiFi. How does your desktop have a cellular connection? You should clarify your question by editing it

Comment: @Ramhound: OP says "I was able to hit the API from another device(smart phone) at home which is on the same wifi. But as soon as I turn the wifi off and switch to cellular data" – that sounds more like a smart phone than a desktop. (Though, some laptops do have LTE modems built in...)

Comment: @user1686 - My brain filtered out information about a mobile phone by accident

Comment: @user1686 you are right. I was talking about turning off wifi on my smart phone.

Comment: @FrankThomas I only have a single router. So my desktop is connected to router and I am hitting the API via chrome on my smartphone. The desktop is connected to the router using ethernet cable. It's how it get's it's internet. And I use the wifi of the router on my phone. I am able to hit the api from phone when I have wifi turned on on my phone but if i switch my phone to cellular data then I can't

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I am trying to access this from outside world. I barely know anything about networking but I know that 192 is private IP address and therefore it's not exposed to the internet

More precisely 192.168.x.x, not the entirety of 192.x.x.x.

(It's private in the sense that it has no meaning globally, only within your own LAN – the rest of the internet doesn't know *where* it is, and there is no point in hiding it either as the address has practically no identifying information.)

> I tried to access https://192.168.0.xxx:8181/WeatherForecast from outside but I couldn't.

This would never work with 192.168.x addresses, again, because it's a private address – there exist millions of LANs that use the same private address range, so outside networks have no idea where your 192.168.0.xxx is supposed to be found.

(On the other hand, this *is* what you'd do with an IPv6 address, as typically those are globally assigned.)

"Port forwarding" would be better named "Address translation". When using port forwarding, you have to access the *router's* public address and it translates the connection to the specified internal address.

> So I tried IP of my router 100.71.xx.xx

That's actually **also a private address**. It only has meaning within the ISP's network, but similarly cannot be accessed from outside the ISP. The 100.64.x.x – 100.127.x.x range (aka 100.64.0.0/10) is the **CGNAT** private address range.

In other words, your ISP likely ran out of public IPv4 addresses and is no longer issuing them to users directly; the address that websites see (i.e. what's reported through "What is my IP" sites) is a temporary assignment and in extreme cases might even be shared between several customers.

You'll need to contact the ISP and see if they can give you a dedicated IPv4 address; if not, then your only possibility for inbound IPv4 access is through third-party proxy or VPN tunnels (some commercial VPNs offer this, some people set up personal VPNs for that purpose, there are things like Ngrok purely for HTTP, etc).

It's possible that you could connect through IPv6 if both ISPs (home and cellular) support it (check whether your computer has a global IPv6 address).

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. :/ And no I don't have IPv6 address. It's blank. I can look into NGrok and and VPN tunnel. Probably VPN tunnel because I would later want to access files on my computer. I dont think that would be possible with just http

Answer (score 0):

There's another issue though. If your external ip address is not static then you'll have a difficult time connecting from outside, you will need to use a dynamic DNS service. Also if you have more than one router you have to decide on which one you'll have the device connected to and configure your port forwarding accordingly. Idealy you'd want to have your device connected to the main router.